# Google Fit / Apple Health bar chart style with MPAndroidChart/Charts library

Tags: java, android, ios, mpandroidchart, ios-charts

I want to add chart like bar chart in Google Fit / Apple Health app like attach pictures, but could not find how to achieve it with MPAndroidChart / Charts library. First look it like CandleStickChart but it is not.

[image: Apple Health]

[image: Google Fit]

Comment: Any leads appreciated.

Comment: @IOSDev I can do like that use Candle Stick, but with heavy modified original source code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use MPAndroidChart / Charts library and are NOT afraid of changing library code, you can use BarChartView, make rounded corners in

```
@objc open func drawDataSet(context: CGContext, dataSet: IBarChartDataSet, index: Int)
```

and after this set entries array with "data" and "no data" bars.

```
let entries = [BarChartDataEntry(x: 1, yValues: [20, 3, 10])]
```

where 20 - data, 3 - no data, 10 - data

Make set:

```
let set = BarChartDataSet(entries: entries, label: "Label")
set.colors = [
            color,
            color.withAlphaComponent(0),
            color
        ]
```

Think main idea is clear. But this approach isn't perfect and I don't recommend you to change dependencies.